# How can non-struct type extends struct functions

Tags: go, go-gorm

***update***: Ok I made it wrong. `CustomJSONType`'s functions can not access the fields of the struct that it is embedded into, for which both `User` and `IntList` should define `Scan` and `Value` of their own or try other workarounds.

---

***original post on 2021-6-21***

I am using GORM and trying to define some custom types like `User` and `IntList`.

```
type User struct {
    Id      int
    Name    string
    Email   string
}

type IntList []int
```

And as is known GORM custom type must implement `Value` and `Scan` functions. Here's what I did - I defined a `CustomJSONType` which implements `Value` and `Scan` like this:

```
type CustomJSONType struct {}

func (t *CustomJSONType) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    bytes, ok := src.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("invalid input type")
    }
    err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, t)
    if err != nil{
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func (t CustomJSONType) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(t)

    if err != nil {
        return []byte{}, err
    }
    return bytes, err
}

func (t CustomJSONType) GormDataType() string {
    return "json"
}
```

To equip `User` with `Value` and `Scan`, all I have to do is to add a single line to the definition of `User`:

**update: it won't work as `CustomJSONType` can't access fields of `User`**

```
type User struct {
    CustomJSONType
    Id      int
    Name    string
    Email   string
}
```

However, I have no idea how to extend `IntList` with `CustomJSONType`. I have to explicitly define `Scan` and `Value` for `IntList`. Even at best I can wrap the implementation of `Value` and `Scan` as independent functions but still have to write signatures for `Scan` and `Value` in `IntList`. Any suggestions to define `IntList` just as simple as `User`?

Comment: Struct types are the only concrete types in which embedding is allowed. Since `IntList` is not a struct type, you cannot embed a `CustomJSONType` in it as you did for `User`.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `Scan` and `Value` implementations on an *empty* struct type? If you expect `CustomJSONType` to "inherit" the fields of the struct in which it is embedded then you should know that that's not what embedding does. In Go there's no type extension.

Comment: Basically you have to explicitly define `Scan` and `Value` for both types - `IntList` *and* `User`. The `CustomJSONType` is useless, all it does is satisfy an interface but the implementation does nothing since `t` in both methods is an **empty** struct, or a pointer to an empty struct.

Comment: @mkopriva thanks! I didn't test my code in the runtime.

Comment: @mkopriva You can fake method extension in Go by embedding an empty value struct as first member with a method with pointer receiver where you use `unsafe.Pointer` to change the type of the receiver to what your struct is embedded in. At least until Go 2: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/18617  Not recommended, but it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "inherit" concept in golang but only combination. Don't like normal OOP language, the struct `CustomJSONType` can't access the data from `IntList` and `User`, so the method `CustomJSONType.Value` can't serialize other types than itself. If you want implement a method once and use it anywhere, I provide an idea bellow.

```golang
package main

import (
    "database/sql/driver"
    "encoding/json"
    "errors"
    "fmt"
)

type CustomJSONType struct {
    data interface{}
}

func (t *CustomJSONType) Scan(src interface{}) error {
    bytes, ok := src.([]byte)
    if !ok {
        return errors.New("invalid input type")
    }
    err := json.Unmarshal(bytes, t.data)
    if err != nil{
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func (t CustomJSONType) Value() (driver.Value, error) {
    bytes, err := json.Marshal(t.data)

    if err != nil {
        return []byte{}, err
    }
    return bytes, err
}

func (t CustomJSONType) GormDataType() string {
    return "json"
}

type User struct {
    Id      int
    Name    string
    Email   string
}

type Project struct {
    user CustomJSONType
}

func (p *Project) SetUser(u User) {
    p.user.data = u
}

func (p *Project) GetUser() User {
    user := p.user.data.(User)
    return user
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I understood you correctly. But you can combine several types, including an array of ints, without creating a structure. They remain a type and are available in functions. But combining types requires a structure, which is why you cannot directly use array addressing.

```
type IntArr []int
type AnyStruct struct{
    Uses bool
}
type TestIntArrStruct struct{
    IntArr
    AnyStruct
}
func(arr *IntArr) Add(i ...int){
    *arr = append(*arr, i...)
}
func(anyStruct *AnyStruct) Invert(){
    anyStruct.Uses = !anyStruct.Uses
}
var a TestIntArrStruct
a.Add(1,2,3)
a.Invert()
```

You can see it here:
https://play.golang.org/p/MF5eMcgmeak